# Floating-point type with extended range

Tags: c, floating-point, gpgpu, multiprecision

I need to represent floating-point numbers of very small orders (for example, 0.6745 × 2<sup>-3000</sup>) in C. It is necessary that such support was platform independent (works on both the CPU and GPU-CUDA). The big length of the significand is not required.

I can not use high-precision libraries (GMP, MPFR, etc.) because they do not work on the GPU. On the other hand CUDA does not support the `long double` type. Is there any solution? Is it possible to somehow implement a custom floating-point type?

Comment: Your example value is within the range of a `double`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth thank you. I corrected example.

Comment: Maybe the high-precision libraries can be adapted to the GPU? IIRC they all have fallback pure-C implementations of their algorithms. [CUMP](http://www.hpcs.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/~nakayama/cump/) appears to be such a project.

Comment: @user4815162342 CUMP supporting only three arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication).

Comment: What operations do you need?

Comment: Stackoverflow is *not* a forum. It's a question & answer site. What you wrote is a question. Since you seem to have solved it by yourself, please remove the solution from your question and post it as an answer. Read [faq] for more information.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth add, sub, mul, div, pow.

Comment: how much range do you want? and how much precision of the significant do you need?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc range shall be not less than 2^{8192}, precision shall be not less than 53 bit (as in double)

Comment: well, then it's not "the big length of the significand not required"

Answer (score 1):

You could work in log-space, that is represent each number as e<sup>x</sup> where x is your standard floating point type:

- addition/subtraction (and summation more generally) can be performed using the [log-sum-exp trick](http://machineintelligence.tumblr.com/post/4998477107/the-log-sum-exp-trick), i.e.

  - e<sup>x</sup>+e<sup>y</sup> = e<sup>x</sup> (1+e<sup>y-x</sup>) = e<sup>x + log(1+exp(y-x))</sup>
- multiplication/division become addition/subtraction

  - e<sup>x</sup> × e<sup>x</sup> = e<sup>x+y</sup>
- raising to a power is fairly straightforward

  - (e<sup>x</sup>)^(e<sup>x</sup>) = e<sup>x exp(y)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I wrote simple solution (using [this](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/264/papers/hauser.pdf) work):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define DOUBLE_PRECISION 53

/*  DOUBLE PRECISION FLOATING-POINT TYPE WITH EXTENDED EXPONENT     */

typedef struct Real {
    double sig;     //significand
    long exp;       //binary exponent
} real;

/*  UNION FOR DIVISION DOUBLE BY 2^POW                              */

union DubleIntUnion
{
    double      dvalue;
    uint64_t    ivalue;
};


/*  PLACE SIGNIFICAND OF REAL NUMBER IN RANGE [1, 2)            */

inline real adjust(real x){
    real y;
    y.exp = x.exp;
    y.sig = x.sig;
    if(y.sig == 0){
        y.exp = 0;
    } else if (fabs(y.sig) >= 2.0){
        y.exp = y.exp + 1;
        y.sig = y.sig / 2;
    } else if(fabs(y.sig) < 1){
        y.exp = y.exp - 1;
        y.sig = y.sig * 2;
    }
    return y;
}

/*  PLACE SIGNIFICAND OF REAL NUMBER IN RANGE [1, 2) FOR TINY NUMBER    */
/*  FOR EXAMPLE, AFTER SUBTRATION OR WHEN SET REAL FROM DOUBLE          */

inline real adjusttiny(real x){
    real y;
    y.exp = x.exp;
    y.sig = x.sig;
    while(1){
        x.exp = y.exp;
        x.sig = y.sig;
        y = adjust(x);
        if(x.exp == y.exp && x.sig == y.sig)
            break;
    }
    return y;
}

real set(double x){
    real y;
    real z;
    y.sig = x;
    y.exp = 0;
    return adjusttiny(y);
};

real set(real x){
    real y;
    y.exp = x.exp;
    y.sig = x.sig;
    return y;
};

/*  ARITHMETIC OPERATIONS   */

//divide x by 2^pow. Assert that x.exp - pow > e_min
inline double div2pow(const double x, const int pow)
{
    DubleIntUnion diu;
    diu.dvalue = x;
    diu.ivalue -= (uint64_t)pow << 52;      // subtract pow from exponent
    return diu.dvalue;
}

//summation
inline real sum(real x, real y){            
    real sum;
    int dexp = abs(x.exp - y.exp);

    if (x.exp > y.exp){
        sum.exp = x.exp;
        if(dexp <= DOUBLE_PRECISION){           
            sum.sig = div2pow(y.sig, dexp);     // divide y by 2^(x.exp - y.exp)
            sum.sig = sum.sig + x.sig;
        } else sum.sig = x.sig;
    } else if (y.exp > x.exp){
        sum.exp = y.exp;
        if(dexp <= DOUBLE_PRECISION){           
            sum.sig = div2pow(x.sig, dexp);     // divide x by 2^(y.exp - x.exp)
            sum.sig = sum.sig + y.sig;
        } else
            sum.sig = y.sig;
    } else {
        sum.exp = x.exp;
        sum.sig = x.sig + y.sig;
    }
    return adjust(sum);
}

//subtraction
inline real sub(real x, real y){            
    real sub;
    int dexp = abs(x.exp - y.exp);

    if (x.exp > y.exp){
        sub.exp = x.exp;
        if(dexp <= DOUBLE_PRECISION){           
            sub.sig = div2pow(y.sig, dexp); // divide y by 2^(x.exp - y.exp)
            sub.sig = x.sig - sub.sig;
        } else sub.sig = x.sig;
    } else if (y.exp > x.exp){
        sub.exp = y.exp;
        if(dexp <= DOUBLE_PRECISION){           
            sub.sig = div2pow(x.sig, dexp); // divide x by 2^(y.exp - x.exp)
            sub.sig = sub.sig - y.sig; 
        } else sub.sig = -y.sig;
    } else {
        sub.exp = x.exp;
        sub.sig = x.sig - y.sig;
    }
    return adjusttiny(sub);
}

//multiplication
inline real mul(real x, real y){            
    real product;
    product.exp = x.exp + y.exp;
    product.sig = x.sig * y.sig;
    return adjust(product);
}

//division
inline real div(real x, real y){            
    real quotient;
    quotient.exp = x.exp - y.exp;
    quotient.sig = x.sig / y.sig;
    return adjust(quotient);
}
```

At first glance is working correctly. Maybe I missed something or that implementation can be accelerated?

How I can implement functions `floor` and `ceil` on such numbers?

Comment: Because this code is C++, `abs()` is overloaded and therefore this works, as C++.  But the post is tagged `C` and `abs()` works for integers and so this code fails the math portion.  Suggest posting answers using the programming language of the post.

Comment: On the math side, 1) IMO, do not see the value of using the range `(1/2, 2)` rather than a single binary range `[1, 2)`.  Using a fixed range (when `exp > LONG_MIN`) would simplify various operations.  2) There are lots of problems with code like `1 << x.exp - y.exp` with is UB should the difference exceed `long` bit width and 3) code like `sum.sig = sum.sig + y.sig;` with does not detect overflow.

Comment: @chux thank you. I'll try to take into account your comments and corrected implementation

Comment: if you're storing a separate exponent, then why don't just store the significand as an integer? double has its own exponent and adjusting the external exponent one more time seem to be inefficient

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc if store significand as an integer, I'm afraid there will be problems with rounding

Comment: Then round it yourself. There will be less problem handling 2 different exponents at a time

Answer (score 0):

If you need very big exponents then [symmetric level-index arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_level-index_arithmetic) may fit your needs. However the accuracy is harder to predict, therefore you may need more precision for the LI (level-index) value to compensate. One common way to improve precision is [double-double arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic) which is also used much on CUDA.

There are also numerous multiprecision libraries on CUDA like [CUMP](http://www.hpcs.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/~nakayama/cump/)

Some more information:

- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/512234/gpump-multiple-precision-arithmetic-on-the-gpu-/
- http://individual.utoronto.ca/haojunliu/courses/ECE1724_Report.pdf
- http://gcl.cis.udel.edu/publications/meetings/090709_ARLvisit/090709_Library4GPU.pdf
- http://www.cra.org/Activities/craw_archive/dmp/awards/2009/Padron/proposal_omar_dreu_09.pdf